# NodeJs fs.close() TypeError: fd must be a file descriptor

Tags: node.js

Im using nodejs to write on a file.

```
fs.open(path.join(reportPath), 'a', 666, ( e, fd ) => {
   fs.write( fd, `There is a company named ${companyName}` + os.EOL, null, 'utf8', () => {
      fs.close( (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('write successfull')
     })
   })
 })
```

Its returning an error, actually the file are written but the error make my server stop. because of the `throw err`

here the error message:

```
TypeError: fd must be a file descriptor
    at Object.fs.close (fs.js:608:11)
    at C:\DATA\source\code\build\modules\desc\controller.js:199:42
    at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:685:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to pass an file-descriptor on fs.close()

```
fs.open(path.join(reportPath), 'a', 666, ( e, fd ) => {
   fs.write( fd, `There is a company named ${companyName}` + os.EOL, null, 'utf8', () => {
      fs.close(fd, (err) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('write successfull')
     })
   })
 })
```